# Can I have 2 unique keys on 2 columns but not combination?

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, unique-key

I have a table

```
table userinfo (
     user,
     email,
     address,
     primary key(user)
);
```

In this table 'user' field is same as 'email' at the time of insertion. But user can change their 'email' latter on. 
So i want email to be unique as well and insert query to fail if email already exists in the table.

Is it Possible?

Thanks in advance and this is just an example.

Comment: If you are requiring email to be unique, then why not make that your primary key?  (I don't mean to reignite the religious debate on natural vs surrogate keys, but if you genuinely want to impose a uniqueness constraint in the database layer then it *might* be a sensible solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, add a `UNIQUE` constraint

```
table userinfo (
     user,
     email,
     address,
     primary key(user),
     CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (email)
);
```

the table will now have unique `USER` and unique `Email`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple indexes on a table.  So if you create 2 unique indexs just on the columns you want, it will work how you want.  If you create 1 index on multiple columns it is the combination of those columns that needs to be unique.